# Many to Many in DynamoDB requires additional queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

After reading a lot about how to handle many to many relationships in DynamoDB, I've come to the following solution.

Let's say a `User` has many `Projects`, and a `Project` can have many `User`s.

I've created a single table design with the following attributes:

```
PK --------- SK --------- entityType --------- name --------- GSI1--------- 
user_1       user_1       User                 Foo       
user_2       user_2       User                 Bar       
project_1    project_1    Project              My Project
project_1    pm_1         ProjectMember                       user_1  
project_1    pm_2         ProjectMember                       user_2
```

I can get the user's projects by using the GSI, and the project's users by using the PK and SK starts with `pm_`.

But when I get the project's users I get the **ids**. Now I need to get the whole information about each user.

Does running a batch get is the best practice here? I don't want to copy the user details to each `pm` row.

Comment: Agree that you should not replicate user details into the project items. Yes, I would use [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) with multiple user IDs. Note that it's a 'batch get', not a 'batch query' and you supply the full composite keys of each item you want to get.